# Rails 301 Redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I would like to redirect multiple entries to my landing page to one url.

The following urls, `http://mysite.com` and `http://www.mysite.com`, would redirect to `http://www.mysite.com/` using 301 redirection. How can/should this be done in Rails?

Comment: which webserver are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this [post](http://bluediapente.com/posts/2012/02/10/how-to-do-www-to-non-www-301-redirect-on-your-heroku-rails-app) and decided to redirect using non-www urls.

Answer (score 30):

Using 301 redirect in Rails

```
class RedirectController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to :root, :status => :moved_permanently
  end
end
```

Answer (score 22):

I didn't try this, but something like this should work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :correct_domain!

  private
  def correct_domain!
    unless request.host == 'www.mysite.com'
      redirect_to root_url, :status => 301  # or explicitly 'http://www.mysite.com/'
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure if the trailing slash is present in the host attribute...

Comment: Thanks Vapire, but I'm receiving a redirect loop error when I add this to my app controller.

Comment: Needs to be done in the home controller, worked nicely for me.

Comment: @Dru just a guess but maybe your ```root_url``` doesn't match your ```request.host``` (ie. doesn't include www).